# How to create a model without primary key in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to create a model 'Relation' which extends ActiveRecord::Base, set it's table name as 'questions_tags', and without primary key. What should I do?

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'questions_tags' # set table name, right?

  # how to define 'no-pk'?
  
end
```

**UPDATE**

---

I know use 'create_table' can solve this problem, but this is just what I want to know: What is the magic behind `create_table(:id=>false)`? How can I get the same effect without using `create_table(:id=>false)`?

Comment: According to me there is no magic. `create_table` has an extra option, whether or not the `id`-column must be created. That's all. When you are asking for "the magic": do you mean the code, the sql-statement that is generated, or something else ... ?

Comment: If you wanna know what is going on behind the scenes, I would suggest to dig depper in the Rails API Documentation:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html,
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html,
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @nathanvda,auralbee: thank you both. I'm new to rails, maybe I need to read more articles about the ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a migration that looks like this:

```
class CreateQuestionsTags < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
   create_table :questions_tags, {:id => false, :force => true} do |t|
     ...
     t.timestamps
   end
  end

  def self.down
   drop_table :questions_tags
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to create a pivot table, as it looks like from the table name, then AR will handle that in the background.

However, if you're looking to create a table with more feilds then:
1) rename your table to "realtions" please
2) use a primary key "id"

There's no good reason not to be using a primary key in a table, and it is very likely that you might well find yourself regretting it later.

Answer (score -9):

Why don't you want a PK?

Active Record expects a PK, and I don't see what harm it can do.

Comment: if you're creating legacy DB mappings, that's fine, but join tables in the ActiveRecord pattern/design have primary keys. It's a convention that you can either follow to make your life easier, or constantly fight against.

Comment: There are many times you would not want a primary key. On reporting tables where you do tons of inserts and reads based on non-primary-key columns, you may want as few indexes as possible. Having a  primary key column you're not going to use does nothing but slow inserts.